# Define compiler warning/errors for library functions

Tags: c, gcc, attributes, compiler-warnings

I am wondering if it is possible to generate compiler warnings or errors for specific library functions.

For example, I work all the time on multithreaded programs and I would like to get a compiler warning whenever I try to use a not-threadsafe function like strtok (instead of strtok_r).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the poison pragma: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Pragmas.html

```
#pragma GCC poison strtok
```

Comment: I am interested also in generating errors. I updated the question.

Comment: One option is `-werror` which will elevate all warnings to errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script which checks the generated code against a list of prohibited symbols. E.g. [this script](http://blog.josefsson.org/2009/06/23/thread-safe-functions/) is a good starting point; though you may want to modify it to retrieve symbols via readelf or nm instead of grepping the object code directly.